# show that the hypothesis $\mu(X) < \infty$ can not be omitted

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of bounded complex measurable functions on $X$, and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $X$  then  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n d\mu =\int_X f d\mu$.

show that  the  hypothesis $\mu(X)  < \infty$  can not be omitted

My attempt : I was  thinking about constant function  $f_n= c $

Is there any other example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant function does not work, since $\int_X f_n \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_X f \mathrm{d}\mu$ in this case. However, you can choose $f_n = 1/n$.

Comment: thanks u @gerw  but i have  some confusion  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n d\mu =\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X  \frac{1}{n}d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\mu(X)=0$.

$\int_X f d\mu=0$   here hypothesis omitted

Comment: No, you have $\frac1n \mu(X) = \infty$, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \mu(X) = \infty$.

Comment: ohh  yaa  got it thanks u @gerw

Answer (score 2):

Notation: $M$ is $\mathfrak M.$

Even if $\int_X|f|d\mu\le 1$ for all $n$: Take Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R.$ For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\not \in [n,2n]$ and let $f_n(x)=1/n$ if $x\in [n,2n].$

In general suppose $\mu$ is atomless, i.e. if $A\in M$ and $\mu(A)>0$ then there exists $B\in M$ with $B\subset A$ and $0<\mu(B)<\mu(A).$ Now if $\mu(X)=\infty$ then there is a set $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subset M$  with $n\le\mu(B_n)<\infty,$ so let $f_n=\frac {\chi_{B_n}}{\mu(B_n)}.$

Comment: Exercise: Suppose $\mu$ is atomless and $\mu(A)\ne 0$. Then (i) For any $r\in \Bbb R^+$ there exists $B\subset A$ with $0<\mu(B)<r$.... (ii) For any $r\in (0,\mu(A))$ there exists  $B\subset A$ with $\mu(B)=r.$